# First line missing while reading string using PHP

Tags: php

I am reading a long string coming from an editor using PHP.
It misses the first line. Please see the code below.

```
$separator = "\r\n";
$line = strtok($article, $separator);

while ($line !== false) {
    # do something with $line
    $line = strtok( $separator );
    echo $line;
}
```

If the text is like -

```
Line1Line1Line1Line1 Line1Line1Line1
Line2Line2Line2Line2 Line2Line2Line2
Line3Line3Line3 Line3Line3
```

Then it prints from the second one.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Because you already consumed one line before the loop. `$line = strtok($article, $separator);` will have the first line.

Comment: Also, that's a quite convoluted workaround for reading a file line-wise.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for the hint. Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work...

```
$separator = "\r\n";
$line = strtok($article, $separator);

while ($line !== false) {
    echo $line;
    $line = strtok( $separator );
    
}
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it would be good to include an explanation so that the OP and any future readers can learn from your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have understood now.